# How to encode more than one column with column transformer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to encode more than one column with columtransformer. Do you know how to add those?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
transformer = make_column_transformer(( OneHotEncoder(categories='auto'), [1] ),remainder="passthrough")
X = transformer.fit_transform(X)

LabelEncoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
y = LabelEncoder_Y.fit_transform(y)
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160370/how-to-use-sklearn-column-transformer, does this help?

Comment: use `pd.get_dummies` to OneHotEncode multiple columns

Comment: @Trollsors It might be easier to use pandas for preprocessing data however using sklearn for the same has advantages as preprocessing steps can be used in pipelines and later can be used to cross-validate model performance

Answer (score 3):

For `make_column_transformer` provide a `list` of indices/ column names for columns you need to *encode* and *transform*. For eg, if you need column index 0 and 1:

```
transformer = make_column_transformer( (OneHotEncoder(categories='auto'), 
                                       [0, 1]), remainder="passthrough" )
```