# How to use LabelEncoder in sklearn make_column_tranformer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How to use LabelEncoder in sklearn pipeline?

**NOTE**
The following code works for "OneHotEncoder" but fails for "LabelEncoder", How to use LabelEncoder in this circumstance?

## MWE

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
import sklearn

print(sklearn.__version__) # 0.22.2.post1

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic').head()

le = OneHotEncoder() # this success
# le = LabelEncoder() # this fails

ct = make_column_transformer(
    (le, ['sex','adult_male','alone']),
    remainder='drop')

ct.fit_transform(df)
```

> $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(N\mid E)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(N\cap E)}{\mathsf P(E)}\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(N\cap E\mid F),\mathsf P(F)+\mathsf P(N\cap E\mid F^{\small\complement}),\mathsf P(F^{\small\complement})}{\mathsf P(E\mid F),\mathsf P(F)+\mathsf P(E\mid F^{\small\complement}),\mathsf P(F^{\small\complement})}\end{align}$$

Comment: what error do you receive? and which line of code gives you the error?

Comment: Ideally, LabelEncoder() is for the response variable, so it takes a series and you're trying to apply it to a data frame, hence the error.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63822728/5114585 explains when to use OHE, OE, LE or LB

Answer (score 2):

From the docs, `OneHotEncoder` can take a dataframe and convert the categorical columns into the vectors you see. `LabelEncoder` takes a Series(your y / dependent variable) and generates new labels.

OnHotEncoder's usage: `fit_transform(X,[y])`

LabelEncoder's usage: `fit_transform(y)`

That's why it'll tell you: "`fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`"

Just call `LabelEncoder` `fit_transform` on the y directly if you really want to use it. Here is a similar question: [How to use sklearn Column Transformer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160370/how-to-use-sklearn-column-transformer/54160620)

Here are the docs:

1. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html
2. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

Answer (score 1):

`LabelEncoder` was specially designed for encoding the target variable - `y`. That's why you can't use it to transform multiple columns at the same time as with `OneHotEncoder`.

Sklearn provides `OrdinalEncoder` for such circumstances. It can encode multiple columns at once when encoding features.