# Using Scikit-Learn OneHotEncoder with a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to replace a column within a Pandas DataFrame containing strings into a one-hot encoded equivalent using Scikit-Learn's OneHotEncoder. My code below doesn't work:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
# data is a Pandas DataFrame

jobs_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
jobs_encoder.fit(data['Profession'].unique().reshape(1, -1))
data['Profession'] = jobs_encoder.transform(data['Profession'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
```

It produces the following error (strings in the list are omitted):

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-3a1f568322f5> in <module>()
      3 jobs_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
      4 jobs_encoder.fit(data['Profession'].unique().reshape(1, -1))
----> 5 data['Profession'] = jobs_encoder.transform(data['Profession'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))

/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py in transform(self, X)
    730                                        copy=True)
    731         else:
--> 732             return self._transform_new(X)
    733 
    734     def inverse_transform(self, X):

/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py in _transform_new(self, X)
    678         """New implementation assuming categorical input"""
    679         # validation of X happens in _check_X called by _transform
--> 680         X_int, X_mask = self._transform(X, handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown)
    681 
    682         n_samples, n_features = X_int.shape

/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py in _transform(self, X, handle_unknown)
    120                     msg = ("Found unknown categories {0} in column {1}"
    121                            " during transform".format(diff, i))
--> 122                     raise ValueError(msg)
    123                 else:
    124                     # Set the problematic rows to an acceptable value and

ValueError: Found unknown categories ['...', ..., '...'] in column 0 during transform
```

Here's some sample data:

```py
data['Profession'] =

0         unkn
1         safe
2         rece
3         unkn
4         lead
          ... 
111988    indu
111989    seni
111990    mess
111991    seni
111992    proj
Name: Profession, Length: 111993, dtype: object
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the *full* error trace, as well as a sample of your `data['Profession']`.

Comment: one hot encoder would return  a 2d array of size `data_length x num_categories`. You cannot assign to a single column `df['Profession']`.

Comment: Followup on dd answer. We can use OneHotEncoder for multi column data, while not for LabelBinarizer and LabelEncoder. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54119850/1582366

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So turned out that Scikit-Learns [LabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) gave me better luck in converting the data to one-hot encoded format, with help from [Amnie's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58101528/9035662), my final code is as follows

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

jobs_encoder = LabelBinarizer()
jobs_encoder.fit(data['Profession'])
transformed = jobs_encoder.transform(data['Profession'])
ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(transformed)
data = pd.concat([data, ohe_df], axis=1).drop(['Profession'], axis=1)
```

Comment: This makes you lose the feature names and it works only on a single column since it is designed to be applied to the target variable.

Answer (score 44):

[**OneHotEncoder**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) Encodes categorical integer features as a one-hot numeric array. Its **Transform** method returns a sparse matrix if `sparse=True`, otherwise it returns a 2-d array.

You can't cast a **2-d array** (or sparse matrix) into a **Pandas Series**. You must create a Pandas Serie (a column in a Pandas dataFrame) for each **category**.

I would recommend [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) instead:

```
data = pd.get_dummies(data,prefix=['Profession'], columns = ['Profession'], drop_first=True)
```

**EDIT:**

Using Sklearn OneHotEncoder:

```
transformed = jobs_encoder.transform(data['Profession'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
#Create a Pandas DataFrame of the hot encoded column
ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(transformed, columns=jobs_encoder.get_feature_names())
#concat with original data
data = pd.concat([data, ohe_df], axis=1).drop(['Profession'], axis=1)
```

**Other Options:** If you are doing hyperparameter tuning with [GridSearch](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) it's recommanded to use [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) and [FeatureUnion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) with [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) or directly [make_column_transformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html)

Comment: I want to be able to pickle the instance to use it on new data in the future, that's why I want to use OneHotEncoder, that can't be done with get_dummies right?

Comment: That's right. If you want to use it on new data, you can't use get_dummies.

Comment: IMO there's a problem with the original code in connection with this (correct) sklearn OneHotEncoder solution. The original code has `jobs_encoder.fit(data['Profession'].unique().reshape(1, -1))` but it should be `jobs_encoder.fit(data['Profession'].unique().reshape(-1, 1))`. I discovered this while trying out the solution.

Comment: Now use `.get_feature_names_out()` for feature names

Comment: This answer helped me get most of the way there.  In order for the concat to work properly, you also need to align the index of the new df with the original: `ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(transformed, columns=jobs_encoder.get_feature_names_out(), index=data.index)`

Answer (score 10):

This below is an approach suggested by Kaggle Learn. Do not think there is a simpler way to do so at the moment to go from an original pandas `DataFrame` to a one-hot encoded `DataFrame`.

```
# Apply one-hot encoder to each column with categorical data
OH_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
OH_cols_train = pd.DataFrame(OH_encoder.fit_transform(X_train[low_cardinality_cols]))
OH_cols_valid = pd.DataFrame(OH_encoder.transform(X_valid[low_cardinality_cols]))

# One-hot encoding removed index; put it back
OH_cols_train.index = X_train.index
OH_cols_valid.index = X_valid.index

# Remove categorical columns (will replace with one-hot encoding)
numeric_X_train = X_train.drop(low_cardinality_cols, axis=1)
numeric_X_valid = X_valid.drop(low_cardinality_cols, axis=1)

# Add one-hot encoded columns to numerical features
new_X_train = pd.concat([numeric_X_train, OH_cols_train], axis=1)
new_X_valid = pd.concat([numeric_X_valid, OH_cols_valid], axis=1)
print(new_X_train)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the new `set_output` API from scikit-learn, it is now possible to get a Dataframe output after applying the OneHotEncoder.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
oh= OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False).set_output(transform="pandas")
one_hot_encoded=oh.fit_transform(df[["Profession"]])
df = pd.concat([df,one_hot_encoded],axis=1).drop(columns=["Profession"])
```

Please refer to: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_set_output.html

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. Remove plotly parts if you are not interested in viz. Also change printmd to print if you don't need markdown.

```
def fn_cat_onehot(df):

    """Generate onehoteencoded features for all categorical columns in df"""

    printmd(f"df shape: {df.shape}")

    # NaN handing
    nan_count = df.isna().sum().sum()
    if nan_count > 0:
        printmd(f"NaN = **{nan_count}** will be categorized under feature_nan columns")

    # generation
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

    model_oh = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", sparse=False)
    for c in df.select_dtypes("category").columns:
        printmd(f"Encoding **{c}**")  # which column
        matrix = model_oh.fit_transform(
            df[[c]]
        )  # get a matrix of new features and values
        names = model_oh.get_feature_names_out()  # get names for these features
        df_oh = pd.DataFrame(
            data=matrix, columns=names, index=df.index
        )  # create df of these new features
        display(df_oh.plot.hist())
        df = pd.concat([df, df_oh], axis=1)  # concat with existing df
        df.drop(
            c, axis=1, inplace=True
        )  # drop categorical column so that it is all numerical for modelling

    printmd(f"#### New df shape: **{df.shape}**")
    return df
```

Comment: 'Series' object has no attribute 'select_dtypes'
I get this error when I pass use the function as 
fn_cat_onehot(df_train['property_type'])

Comment: @Nishita you need to pass it as a df not a series. Try a quick  ‘pd.DataFrame(series_name)’

Answer (score 0):

I capsulize @IndreshKumar's solution into a sklearn transformer:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

class CategoricalOneHot(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, list_key_words=None):
        self.oh_dict = {}
        self.list_key_words = list_key_words

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.list_cat_col = []
        for key_word in self.list_key_words:
            self.list_cat_col += [col for col in X.columns if key_word in col]
        for col in self.list_cat_col:
            oh = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", sparse=False)
            oh.fit(X[[col]])
            names = oh.get_feature_names_out()
            self.oh_dict[col] = (oh, names)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        _X = X.copy()
        for col in self.list_cat_col:
            oh = self.oh_dict[col][0]
            df_oh = pd.DataFrame(
                data=oh.transform(_X[[col]]),
                columns=self.oh_dict[col][1],
                index=_X.index)
            _X = pd.concat([_X, df_oh], axis=1)
            _X.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)
        return _X

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tex = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['a', 'a', 'e', 'b'], 'state': ['f', 'c', 'd', 'd']})
    coh = CategoricalOneHot(list_key_words=['city', 'state'])
    print(coh.fit_transform(tex))
```

Example:
Given a data frame with two categorical columns:

```
  city state
0    a     f
1    a     c
2    e     d
3    b     d
```

the output looks like this:

```
   city_a  city_b  city_e  state_c  state_d  state_f
0     1.0     0.0     0.0      0.0      0.0      1.0
1     1.0     0.0     0.0      1.0      0.0      0.0
2     0.0     0.0     1.0      0.0      1.0      0.0
3     0.0     1.0     0.0      0.0      1.0      0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for other folks who might need this, I found an easy solution on https://saturncloud.io/blog/pandas-vs-scikitlearn-onehot-encoding-dataframes/

It's as easy as this (a bunch of it was copy pasted from the link, with some added tweaks):

```
# create OneHotEncoder object
encoder = OneHotEncoder()

# fit and transform color column
one_hot_array = encoder.fit_transform(df[['color']]).toarray()

# create new dataframe from numpy array
one_hot_df = pd.DataFrame(one_hot_array, columns = encoder.get_feature_names(), index = df.index)

#concat with df
data = pd.concat([df, one_hot_df], axis=1).drop(['color'], axis=1)
```

Tadaaah all done!